# Mandrill python API attachment error message

Tags: python-2.7, webapp2, asana, xmlrpclib, mandrill

I'm writing a web app for customer/order handling in python with [asana](https://github.com/pandemicsyn/asana) integration.

For a registered incoming order, an invoice is created as .pdf. This file I want to send to asana as an email attachment using mandrill, because the asana python API doesn't provide attachments yet.

Because mandrill wants the content of the attachment as a base64-encoded string, I create a binary of the pdf using this function:

```
def binaryFile(self, pathToFile):
    binary_obj = xmlrpclib.Binary( open(pathToFile).read() )
    return binary_obj
```

Together with the path of the file, I throw this into mandrill like so:

```
'attachments': [{'content': binaryFile,
                 'name': pathOfFile,
                 'type': 'application/pdf'}]
```

When I try to send the whole thing, this is what I get:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/mandrill.py", line 1215, in send
return self.master.call('messages/send', _params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mandrill.py", line 131, in call
  params = json.dumps(params)
  OverflowError: Overlong 3 byte UTF-8 sequence detected when encoding string
```

Who can hint at what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All right ok, I found the mistake myself, it's in the base64-encoding of course. I'm now doing it like so:

```
import base64

def filetobase64(self, inputfilename):
    return base64.b64encode(open(inputfilename, 'rb').read())
```

Everything works fine now.

No harm meant!

Comment: Wasted so much time and finally got this answer. Thanks alot @creimers. +1. I'm still thinking why we need to do this ? why it can be straight ?